# Problem when setting onFormSubmit trigger from spreadsheet to form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I've made a script that builds different forms and they have assigned an onFormSubmit trigger. On the trigger, I have this trouble.

```js
const form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
```

but the problem is that that script is bounded on the script that builds the forms, not into the form instead. I can't open the form with the Id because it wouldn't work for all the forms

SpreadSheet script

```js
function main(){
 ...
 const formId = form.getId()
  //setup trigger
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
    .forForm(formId)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create()
}
 function onFormSubmit(e){
  ...
  const formResponse = e.response;
  const date = formResponse.getTimestamp()
  const names = getNames()
  ...
 }

 function getNames(){
  ... 
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm() //problem
  ...
 }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by getting the source info from the event parameter

```js
function onFormSubmit(e){
  ...
  const formResponse = e.response;
  const date = formResponse.getTimestamp()
  const formId = e.source.getId()
  const names = getNames(formId)
  ...
 }
```